# what t-test should i use for an experiment on a system? and how to measure improvements in the system, if any?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design

**Updated** fixed a typo and gave more clarification on the data itself.

I need to make a change to a running online system that i have.

So, I need a method to compare the performance of the system (using a KPI score), before the change (we call this A) and after the change (we call this B).

My plan is as follows:

- split the users into two groups A and B
- keep the original version with group A. Give the changes only to group B.
- take daily measurements for group A and for group B
- compare which group shows better measurements

So far I will have this data:

My raw data collected consists of the number of navigations and the number of clicks per user per day. 
I perform additional calculations to get a simpler table of [day, ExperimentA, ExperimentB]. Both expA and expB are in the range [0,1] (they are a KPI or a score that i calculate as measurement of performance for my online system for that given date).

Here is an example of generated table (one row per day):

> Date, Experiment A, Experiment B
>
> 2017/10/01, 0.8, 0.5
>
> 2017/10/02, 0.65, 0.7
>
> 2017/10/03, 0.7, 0.7
>
> etc...

1. How can I check if B is better than A?
   I guess the answer would be to run a t-test?
2. If yes, what should use? an independent t-test or related t-test?

thanks a lot

Comment: Describe your data - is it percentage of users - complaints or index for efficiecy of different machines /users . total sample and subsamples- number for each group ?

Comment: you can think of the raw data collected as a number of navigations and clicks per user per day. I already do additional calculations and get a simple table of <day, expA, expB>. It doesn't matter much what are the valid values for expA and expB but they both have same type and range of values

Comment: @subhashc.davar i have updated the question and reflected your comment. I had a mistake in the example i brought to you. fixed now.

Comment: thanks! But, I can't understand what is better measurements ?

Comment: @subhashc.davar
The higher the values are, the better the system is. Assume, for simplicity, we get in ExpB a fixed score of 0.9 every day but for ExpA we get a fixed score of 0.5 every day, this means that system B is better than A. In this simple example I would say that system B is improving our system by 0.4 score value, which is 40%.